# Formal guarantee that empty packaged_task isn't optimized out?

Tags: c++, std, packaged-task

Below is a simplified version of my scheduler. A single thread processes packaged_tasks in the order they were enqueued.

- `execute` schedules and waits for the completion of a task
- `schedules` enqueues a task and immediately returns to the user
- `drain` simply enqueues an empty task, with the idea being that once we get to it, we know all previously scheduled commands have executed

**The question**: are any guarantees here that `drain` won't be optimized away? I've tested this sample program with several compilers under `-O3` and none optimize the empty lambda call out. Is there enough observable behaviour (manipulation of the `mTasks` list, synchronization barriers, etc.) that this drain implementation is valid? What does the standard say?

```
class Scheduler {
public:
    void processTasks() {
        // Runs on separate thread
        // ... some synchronization here ignored
        while (!mTasks.empty()) {
            auto& tsk = mTasks.front();
            tsk();
            mTasks.pop_front();
        }
    }

    void addTask(std::packaged_task<void(void)> task) {
        std::unique_lock lck(mMutex);
        mTasks.emplace_back(std::move(task));
        mCond.notify_one();
    }

    auto schedule(std::function<void(void)> func) {
        std::packaged_task<void(void)> task{func};
        auto fut = task.get_future();
        addTask(std::move(task));
        return fut;
    }

    void execute(std::function<void(void)> func) {
        auto fut = schedule(std::move(func));
        fut.get();
    }

    void fireAndForget(std::function<void(void)> func) {
        schedule(std::move(func));
    }

    void drain() {
        execute([] {});
    }

    std::list<std::packaged_task<void(void)>> mTasks;
    std::mutex mMutex;
    std::condition_variable mCond;
};

int main() {
    Scheduler sched;
    std::jthread executor{&Scheduler::processTasks, &sched};

    int counter = 0;
    sched.fireAndForget([&] {
        counter++;
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(1s);
    });
    sched.fireAndForget([&] {
        counter++;
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(1s);
    });
    sched.fireAndForget([&] {
        counter++;
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(1s);
    });

    sched.drain();

    assert(counter == 3);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: There is a guarantee that your code will work as you wrote it to work, it is a compiler bug otherwise... Anything more than that is implementation and sometimes hardware dependent.

Comment: This may be a XY problem. Can you explain why you care if the empty function is optimized away? If it is, it should necessarily not have any effect on observable behavior.

Comment: I don't actually care about the function call itself, but if the whole of `drain` is optimized away that breaks the intended effect of waiting for the preceeding tasks to finish.